# How to display data retrieved from firebase in react naive for ios

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-ios

My team is working on a tutoring app where students send in requests from the student side to the tutor side. We are able to reference firebase for out data and see it in the console. But we are not able to display on the page.
This is the tutor side code here:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, Text, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import firebaseRef from './Firebase';


export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = ({
            sessions: []
        });
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        const { uid } = firebaseAuth.currentUser
        firebaseRef.database().ref('Sessions/' + uid).on('value', function (snapshot) {
            sessions = snapshot.val()
            this.setState({
                sessions: sessions,
                sessions,
              });
      })
    }

    getSessionsRef = () => {
        return firebaseRef.database().ref('sessions')
      }

    render(){
        const {sessions} = this.state
        return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList>
                <Text>{sessions}</Text>
            </FlatList>
        </View>
         )
        }
    }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent:'center',
        padding:-1.5
    }
});
```

Comment: Change the line right after your render to " const {sessions} = this.state.sessions"

Comment: Your issues is in Flatlist. Thats not how you use Flatlist. Flatlist requires certain props. Here is official docs https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```js
<FlatList
  data={sessions}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
  renderItem={({item}) => (
    <Text>{item}</Text>
  )}
/>
```